# Why am I getting a NoMethodError when calling an instance method from global scope?

Tags: ruby

I have searched around for the answer to this and I can see a lot of similar problems but I still do not understand what I am doing wrong here. I have declared a Ruby class and attempted to new it and then call some instance methods on the instance, so why do I get the NoMethodError on my start method?

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    self.class.reset
  end

  def self.reset
    ...
  end

  def self.start(port)
    ...
  end
end

test = MyClass.new
test.start '8082'  <- here <- undefined method `start' for #<MyClass:0x2f494b0> (NoMethodError)
```

As you can see I am a Ruby noob. Any help would be appreciated. I can change my class structure but I would really like to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `MyClass::start` is a class method, not an instance method (because `def self.start`, not `def start`), so it's invoked `MyClass.start`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Wow, OK, I am really thinking about this the wrong way around. Thank you for explaining that (I normally use C++ so this is much different). That worked, If you post it as the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

here `start` is a class method.

By your current approach, you can use it in the following way

`MyClass.start '8080'`

But if you want to use it on `instance` of `class` then use the following code

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    self.class.reset
  end

  def self.reset
    ...
  end

  def start(port)
    ...
  end
end

test = MyClass.new
test.start '8080'
```

Comment: `reset` should probably be an instance method, too.

Comment: You should probably explain the significance of `self` and its meaning in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are using start as a Class variable, the method names preceded with self-keyword make those methods as Class methods. So if you really want to not change your class then you should call it like this:

> MyClass.start '8080'

Else you can remove the self from your reset and start methods and make them as Instance methods and use them as:

> test = MyClass.new
>
> test.start '8082'